# "...\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value -1073741795

Tags: flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-code, gradle

Followed these instructions to install flutter for windows.
https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows

flutter doctor shows no errors.
When I do:

```
 flutter create myapp
 cd myapp
 flutter run -v
```

It should connect through USB to my android 11 phone
But flutter give the following output:

```
[   +1 ms] [  +11 ms] build succeeded.
[+1398 ms] > Task :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug FAILED
[   +2 ms] :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug (Thread[Execution worker Thread 3,5,main]) completed. Took 5.176 secs.
[   +2 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[   +4 ms] * What went wrong:
[   +1 ms] Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
[   +1 ms] > Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value -1073741795
```

Dart SDK 3.2.3
Flutter SDK 3.16.3
myapp 1.0.0+1

Flutter run --verbose:

```
[  +86 ms] [   +9 ms] build succeeded.
[ +703 ms] > Task :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug FAILED
[  +20 ms] :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug (Thread[Execution worker Thread 3,5,main]) completed. Took 3.555 secs.
[  +48 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[  +32 ms] * What went wrong:
[   +1 ms] Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
[   +1 ms] > Process 'command 'C:\Users\Ramon\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value -1073741795
[   +3 ms] * Try:
[   +1 ms] > Run with --debug option to get more log output.
[   +1 ms] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
[   +1 ms] * Exception is:
[   +1 ms] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter
.java:142)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:140
)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:128)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:77)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46
)
[   +4 ms]      at
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.jav
a:51)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperation
Runner.java:204)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperation
Runner.java:199)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
[   +5 ms]      at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:69)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.
java:327)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.
java:314)
[   +4 ms]      at
org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecut
ionGraph.java:307)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecut
ionGraph.java:293)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:417)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:339)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
[   +1 ms]      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
[   +1 ms]      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
[   +1 ms]      at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[   +1 ms] Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
'C:\Users\Ramon\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value -1073741795
[   +4 ms]      at
org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:415)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecAction.execute(DefaultExecAction.java:38)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecActionFactory.exec(DefaultExecActionFactory.java:202)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.exec(DefaultProject.java:1171)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.exec(DefaultProject.java:1166)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.api.Project$exec$8.call(Unknown Source)
[   +1 ms]      at BaseFlutterTask.buildBundle(flutter.groovy:1350)
[   +1 ms]      at BaseFlutterTask$buildBundle.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
[   +1 ms]      at FlutterTask.build(flutter.groovy:1481)
[   +1 ms]      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[   +1 ms]      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
[   +4 ms]      at
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[   +1 ms]      at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:125)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:58)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:51)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:29)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$3.run(TaskExecution.java:236)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
[   +4 ms]      at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeAction(TaskExecution.java:221)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeActions(TaskExecution.java:204)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(TaskExecution.java:187)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.execute(TaskExecution.java:165)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:89)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:40)
[   +4 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:53)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:50)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperation
Runner.java:204)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperation
Runner.java:199)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
[   +4 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:50)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:40)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:68)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:38)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:41)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:74)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:55)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:29)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.executeDelegateBroadcastingChanges(CaptureStateAft
erExecutionStep.java:124)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:80)
[   +4 ms]      at
org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:58)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:36)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithoutCache(BuildCacheStep.java:181)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.lambda$execute$1(BuildCacheStep.java:71)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.Either$Right.fold(Either.java:175)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.execution.caching.CachingState.fold(CachingState.java:59)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:69)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:47)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:36)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:25)
[   +5 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:36)
[   +2 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:22)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:110)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipUpToDateStep.java:56)
[   +2 ms]      at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:56)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38)
[   +3 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:73)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:44)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedS
tep.java:37)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedS
tep.java:27)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:89)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:50)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:114)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:57)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:76)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:50)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.executeWithNoEmptySources(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:254)
[   +5 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:91)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:56)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:
32)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:
21)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedSte
p.java:38)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:43)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:31)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$4.withWorkspace(TaskExecution.java:281)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
[   +4 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:37)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:27)
[   +2 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:44)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:33)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:76)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:139
)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:128)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:77)
[   +4 ms]      at
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46
)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.jav
a:51)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperation
Runner.java:204)
[   +5 ms]      at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperation
Runner.java:199)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:69)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.
java:327)
[   +4 ms]      at
org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.
java:314)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecut
ionGraph.java:307)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecut
ionGraph.java:293)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:417)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:339)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
[   +1 ms]      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
[   +1 ms]      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
[   +4 ms]      at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[   +1 ms] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[   +1 ms] BUILD FAILED in 6s
[   +2 ms] 5 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 4 up-to-date
```

running on windows 10 64 Enterprise LTSC 1809;

CPU AMD Phenom II X4 CPU

Comment: For what `cd myapp` is for?

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj It is supposed to be an android app. But i didn't write anything additional to what was there from creating the project. There is some sample code in it. A screen which you can tap and it will count the number of taps.

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj ```cd myapp``` is to navigate into the project folder.

Comment: I think you have to specify the file you want to run , something like `flutter run lib/main.dart`

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj flutter run lib/main.dart from from the project folder seems to give the same result. Also creating and running an app through android studio or VS code with flutter extension seems to give the result.

Comment: Seems you've upgraded flutter and there are something dirty in cache. Have you tried to clean, upgrade, removing .gradle folder and re-running.

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj Thank you for the suggestions so far. So what i have tried:

1. Delete ...\User\Me\.gradle
2. Delete C:\flutter and re-extract flutter_windows_3.16.3-stable.zip to this folder.
3. Unistall android studio, 
4. delete following folders:  .\AppData\Local\Android\,  .\Local\.dartServer\,  .\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2023.1\,  .\Roaming\.dart\, .\Roaming\.dart-tool\, .\Roaming\.flutter, .\Roaming\.flutter_tool_state, .\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio2023.1\, .\Local\Pub\ 
5. Reinstall android-studio-2023.1.1.26-windows

Still seem to get: assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: When Android studio is used to create a new flutter project i get:

Project Creation Error: Flutter create command was unsuccessful. Run Flutter Doctor.

Flutter doctor does not give any error. And when using the command line to create a new project there is no error. 

Also my CPU is a quite old AMD Phenom II X4 which does not seem to support running a virtual android machine. Don't know if this matters for this issue.

Comment: ciao.  I have no other suggestions so far. One thing you have to change is that C:\flutter is NOT the right folder to put your sdk/framework. You are working in a root directory of windows where permissions are limited, you have to use C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\flutter instead.

Comment: Hi! I extracted the flutter zip to C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\flutter\ changed the path in environment variables and reinstalled android studio.
It is still not able to run, but the output has changed a bit. Now it doesn't show  ```assembleDebug failed with exit code 1``` anymore but only
```Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
...\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value -1073741795```

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj appreciating your support. Also during the setup of Android Studio I noticed a few errors in the log of the installation Wizard:
```Running Android Emulator hypervisor driver installer
[SC] ControlService FAILED 1062:

The service has not been started.

[SC] DeleteService SUCCESS
[SC] StartService FAILED with error 4294967201.
Creating Android virtual device```

Comment: First of all, you are welcome bro. Unfortunately there are not a lot of suggestions in a rare case like this. Anyway,  if you are working in android studio you have not the necessity to run your app by commands. Just run as traditionally by run menu (android studio thinks by it's self to run all commands in order to run your app). The second suggestion is that to launch your android studio as admin (right click on it's icon -> properties -> advanced -> check "run as administrator"). If you have antivirus exclude paths of android studio, flutter.bat and gradle from it's supervision.

Comment: please Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. and then paste that output into your question post.

Comment: @starball The --stacktrace and --info seem to be gradle option. When flutter is run it seems to start gradle automatically. Is there a way to feed these options to gradle from flutter? But I was able to run flutter with --verbose option.

Comment: I though it might be related to the not up to date OS I was running (windows 10 64 Enterprise LTSC 1809). So I did a clean install to Windows 22H2 19045.3803. But surprisingly the issue was exactly the same. Can it be something hardware related, the old AMD Phenom II X4 CPU maybe? On another system with a i7-4720HQ CPU running Windows 10 I used the same installation procedure. Here it worked without a problem.

Comment: Hi, i'm following this discussion and I think the issue is with the AMD Phenom II X4 CPU, I have the same error with the same CPU, any idea how to solve such issue ?

Comment: Sadly I haven't found a solution to the problem until now. I started to use a different system. But if anyone finds a solution I am eager to hear about it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be hardware related.

The system is running on an AMD Phenom II X4 CPU.

Someone else running on the same CPU reported having the same issues.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).